# Moving circles along a ray to eliminate location check

Tags: javascript, jquery, computational-geometry

I have a function that moves circles out of the way of an expanding circle. It moves them along a ray from the center of the expanding circle through the center of the circle to move. This allows all surrounding circles to move without overlapping.

Here's a diagram to better explain this:

[image: circles]

I expand the size of the red circle from 100px to 200px. I want to move all the blue circles out of the way by half the difference ( (200-100)/2 = 50px, in this example ) along the gray line (with the gray line being different for each blue circle).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/uLu7v/)

```
$this.siblings( ".circle" ).each( function() {

    var $this = $( this ),
        circle = $this.data(),
        circleX = circle.left + circle.radius,
        circleY = circle.top + circle.radius,
        a = Math.abs( hoveredY - circleY ),
        b = Math.abs( hoveredX - circleX ),
        c = Math.sqrt( ( a*a ) + ( b*b ) ),
        A = Math.acos( b / c ), 
        C = 90 * ( Math.PI / 180 ),
        B = C - A,
        sinA = Math.sin( A ),
        sinB = Math.sin( B ),
        sinC = Math.sin( C ),
        newc = c + ( expand / 2 ),
        newa = ( newc * sinA ) / sinC,
        newb = ( newc * sinB ) / sinC,
        newX = hoveredX + ( hoveredX > circleX ? -newb : newb ),
        newY = hoveredY + ( hoveredY > circleY ? -newa : newa ),
        left = newX - circle.radius,
        top = newY - circle.radius;

    $this.animate( { 

        "left": left,
        "top": top

    }, 75 );

});
```

`hoveredX` and `hoveredY` are the left and top coordinates of the red circle and `expand` is how much the red circle is expanding in pixels.

Mathematically, I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I got this way working, and it's fine (although I'm not opposed hearing better solutions). But the one part I don't like about this function are the two lines:

```
newX = hoveredX + ( hoveredX > circleX ? -newb : newb ),
newY = hoveredY + ( hoveredY > circleY ? -newa : newa ),
```

What bugs me is that I'm having to do the check at all. Those two lines are basically saying, "If the circle is on the left/top do it one way, and if it's on the right/bottom do it another way". I feel like I'm missing something earlier in the function that could be solved by switching the sides of operators, adding instead of subtracting, or getting the absolute value.

Comment: `a = Math.abs(` is why you have to check. Are you sure you need absolute values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had two thoughts. One was ... You really only need an angle and a distance. The distance is the amount you expand and the angle can be derived from the x/y coordinates.

http://jsfiddle.net/uLu7v/38/

first you calculate the angle:

```
var angle = Math.atan2(hoveredY - circleY, hoveredX - circleX);
```

Then you calculate the distance they move:

```
var topMove = ((expand /2 ) * Math.sin(angle)); // sin for Y
var leftMove = ((expand /2 ) * Math.cos(angle)); // cos for X
```

then use jQuery's built in animate `+=`:

```
$this.animate( { 
    "left": "-=" + leftMove + "px",
    "top":  "-=" + topMove + "px"
}, 75 );
```

Tada!

**Edit:-** A couple of improvements in the code not supplied in the question:

In `function inCircle()` change the return statement to `return (mouseDistance <= radius);` Using the ternary operator to return a boolean? ... I'm sure it used to return some other values right?

In `$( ".circle" ).click(` :

```
if(!$( this ).data( "clicked" ) && inCircle( $( this ), event.pageX, event.pageY ) ) {

    $( this ).data( "clicked", true );
    setLocations( this, 200, event );

} else {

    resetLocations();
    $( this ).data( "clicked", false );

};
```

Makes it cleaner but not a real improvement otherwise, more of a preference.

In `function setLocations()` your circle parameter conflicts with the local circle variable. I would change the parameter to `circleElement`.

Comment: WOW. I'm not worthy. 20 lines to 3. Up-vote this, people. My demo page gets a lot of hits. I put a link to your SO profile in there with credit.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff thanks. Don't worry we all do this. It took me a couple of goes till i really sat back and thought about it. It happens that I was recently working on some angle/circle/distance stuff myself.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff I just added some other suggestions for the rest of the code which don't really change a great deal.

Comment: Both good changes, updated. Thanks. Who knows how I ended up at a ternary boolean. :) The `circle` in `setLocations()` was a last minute change I made to get ready for this post. It was called `hovered` or something nonintuitive before. Good catch.